# Retrieve Google Analytics 4 event parameters via API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

Google Analytics (particularly version 4, "GA4") has various [predefined events](https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/reference/ga4-events), each with its own parameters. E.g. the `purchase` event has an `items` parameter, which contains data such as `item_id` and `item_name` for each purchased item. JS code on a website can send these events and pass the extra data, and I can actually see the data in the "Analysis hub" in the Google Analytics interface.

Is there a way to also fetch this extra data using the [Google Analytics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1)? There is a way to retrieve *some* [predefined dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema) and also "custom dimensions" (via `customEvent:parameter_name`), but e.g. purchase item data doesn't seem to be a part of that.

Do I have to define custom dimensions (e.g. a `purchasedProductId`) and send them in addition to the `items` parameter, if I want to access this data via API?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: @DaImTo I'm using the Python SDK and `AlphaAnalyticsDataClient`, where I tried to create a `RunReportRequest` with `dimensions=[Dimension(name='item_id')]` and various variations of that name (`itemId`, `productItemId`, `customEvent:item_id`, etc.), but I'm always getting `google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Field ... is not a valid dimension. For a list of valid dimensions and metrics, see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema`.

Comment: Hello, @JanPöschko Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Jan,

Ecommerce reporting is not yet supported in the Google Analytics Data API. I will update this question once I have more information about the timeline of this feature implementation.

Thanks,
Ilya

The Google Analytics Team

Comment: does it support custom event param yet ?

Comment: Hello @dytra did you get the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Per my research, to pull the values of parameters of an event, you need to create a custom dimension. There's a setting dropdown option called "Event Parameter," which will capture the parameter you would like to return in a report. Using your example, you will need to create an event-scoped dimension called something like "purchaseItems", then choose "items" as associated "Event Parameter".

Once you have it set up, you shall be able to include "customEvent:purchaseItems" in your report dimensions setting.